# Zoom to layer extent in OpenLayers using swift

Tags: swift

I've created a imap with different Layers and I have a dropdown in which i am selecting a farm code.

Now I want to add the function, that if there is a farmcode selected, the map should zoom to the entered search result on the map. At the moment, the search result is entered into the layer, but it doesn't zoom to the result.

I have also written an api to get the geojson data, Below is the geojson data which I am getting from my api:

{
data = "{"type" : "FeatureCollection", "features" : [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"MultiPolygon","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:27700"}},"coordinates":[[[[390656.789999999,804731.230000001],[390670.97,804719.670000002],[390682.359999998,804705.86],[390682.691,804705.470000001],[390682.85,804705.271],[390682.998999999,804705.060000001],[390683.14,804704.840000002],[390683.268999999,804704.61],]]]}, "properties": {"gid": 144589, "fid_lpis_d": 1, "farm_code": "001/0004", "objectid_1": 77898, "objectid": 310098, "category": "Woodland", "ift_ioa": "Broadleaved", "country": "Scotland", "centroid_x": 390578.864868, "centroid_y": 804684.433405, "shape_area": 1.556981124281313, "area_in_hectare": 0.14464827966835173}}

Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thank You!
Rutuparna Panda

Comment: are you try to draw polygone on map? or just need zoom on location?.

Comment: Yes. I want to draw multipolygon on apple map. Actually I am new to swift so any help will be really grateful.

Comment: please check answer.

Answer (score 1):

one more thing which lat long you get is wrong

> Latitude and longitude are a pair of numbers (coordinates) used to
> describe a position on the plane of a geographic coordinate system.
> The numbers are in decimal degrees format and range from -90 to 90 for
> latitude and -180 to 180 for longitude.

locations array will fill with `lat` `long`
Eg.

```
var locations = [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.16, 77.36),
                         CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.16, 72.36),
                         CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.16, 75.36),
                         CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.16, 74.36)]
```

get locations cordinates array and draw `MKPolygon` from

```
var locations = //location cordinates array.
let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &locations, count: locations.count)
mapView?.add(polygon)
```

than use `rendererFor` delegate method of `mapView`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay is MKPolygon {
        let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: overlay as! MKPolygon)
        renderer.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.green
        renderer.lineWidth = 1
        return renderer
    }
    
    return MKOverlayRenderer()
}
```